# Memory leak in the code?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I am trying to learn memory in C and wanted to know if there is a memory leak in the following function:

```
void someFunction(void)
{
    unsigned char i;
    for( i=0; i < upperbound; i++ ){
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Do I need to unalloc for the unsigned char `i`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no memory leak in that code. Local variables are allocated on the stack, and deallocated automatically when the function exits. You only have to free data that was allocated with functions like `malloc` or `realloc`.

Note that some library functions return data that was allocated dynamically, and you may be required to deallocate it when you're done. If a function returns a pointer, or modifies a pointer argument you provide as an argument, you must check the documentation to see whether this is necessary.

Comment: *You only have to free data that was allocated with malloc....* Or other allocating functions, such as `realloc` and `strdup`.  Unless its a function like `alloca`.  In truth, there's really no 100% straightforward answer!

Comment: Technically, locals have automatic storage duration.  C has no notion of a "stack" or "heap".

Comment: IMO, _stack_ and _heap_ are conceptual entities that refer to how data allocated in them behaves.